# JavaFX square radio button

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, radio-button

As the title suggests, how do I create a radio button in JavaFX that is in the shape of a square rather than a circle?

If that is not possible, how do I make the radio button have a custom appearance? As in I upload an image of a square radio button in place of the default.

If that is not possible, can I instead make a checkbox act like a radio button?

Comment: Won't this confuse the user, who might reasonably expect round radio buttons to indicate a single selection, while square checkboxes typically allow multiple selections?

Comment: Yes, but what I want to do will in no way confuse the user as I will have the radio buttons in a 3x3 square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your own custom javafx radio button component squareRadioButton or something to that tune. However, consider best programming and UI practices - user expects round selection button to act as a standard radio button on all platforms. First question to ask yourseld here is "Why am I doing this?". Honestly, what you do does not seem right.

If you really want to go that way (because it is what really will benefit the user) I think the easiest choice is to programmatically group a number of choicebox buttons to act as group of radio buttons:

Invoke a handleSelectItem() method on action event for all checkboxes and unselect the one that has been previously selected (if any). You may want to store references to all checkboxes in an array for looping through them and easier management in the future.

```
    @FXML
    public handleSelectItem(){
       for ( CheckBox box : boxList ) {
          // Unselect all checkboxes, except the one that invoked the method
          if( box.isSelected() && box!=this ){
             box.setSelected(false);
          }
       }
    }
```

there is another alternative to try on radio box, which is adjusting the style sheet of it.

you'd have to apply custom css file onyour FXML, or do this for every radio box:

```
    radio.setStyle(
        "-fx-border-color: lightblue; "
        + "-fx-font-size: 20;"
        + "-fx-border-insets: -5; "
        + "-fx-border-radius: 5;"
        + "-fx-border-style: dotted;"
        + "-fx-border-width: 2;"
    );
```

Of course you'd have to customize CSS to fit your needs.

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if answer is useful and acceptable.I have done similar things in the past, so it surely can work.